# LibGDX - Particle Effect Fade Out

Tags: libgdx, fadeout, particles

So I have particle effect(with additive: false) and now I want to create beautiful fade out effect. I've tried to make something like that:

```
Color color = batch.getColor();
batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * alpha);
```

but it doesn't work for particle effect.

Does anyone know how to change alpha of particle effect?

Comment: I haven't used particle effects yet, but the in the documentation it has a [transparency field](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEmitter.Particle.html#field.summary), maybe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't work because I haven't access to this field :/

Answer (score 1):

Solution was pretty simple :D

All You need is:

```
m_particleEffect.getEmitters().get(0).getTransparency().setHigh(0.5f/*alpha*/);
```

Hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [`ParticleEmitter.draw` code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEmitter.java#L234), you'll see the blend mode of the drawing is controlled by the `setAdditive` (which you say you have set to `false`) and [`setPremultipliedAlpha`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEmitter.html#setPremultipliedAlpha-boolean-) methods. It looks like you want to use pre-multiplied alpha, but I'm unsure of how the batch color interacts with the texture color in LibGDX. Try setting pre-multiplied alpha to `true` first.

Comment: Okay I've checked both solutions and results are:
1. If I set Additive true then my particle generate additional light :/
2. If I set Premultiplied Alpha true then white rectangle around particle sprite appear

The best solutions is to find out how I can get access to transparency